# What's a convenient way to setup two objects that physically "plug" into each other?

Tags: godot

I'm making a puzzle game and I need two pieces that look like they fit together (like a DVI port and DVI plug). I want them to be two separate scenes because I want to place and animate them separately.

What's a good way to set this up to make it easy to edit them and keep their shapes in sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put each half in its own scene (A and B).
2. Place both in a scene that's just for editing them (E). This is a normal scene that you don't spawn in gameplay.
3. Edit them in scene E.
4. On the instances of A and B:

   1. "Make Local".

      - This severs the relationship to the saved scene.
   2. "Save Branch as Scene" and overwrite original.

      - This recreates the relationship to the saved scene and updates the scene file.

Comment: To be clear, it is called "Make Local" in Godot 4 too. As far as I can tell "Discard Instancing" was renamed to "Make Local" in Godot 3.1. Addendum: this is the pull request for the rename https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/19729

Comment: @Theraot: Thanks! I've updated my answer.